# Is generating components in render efficient?

Tags: reactjs

In a simple component I have an array of child components. In the parent's `state` (among other things), I hold an array of objects and in the `render` function I construct the child components as:

```
const children = [];
let i = 1;
for(let child of this.state.children){
    children.push(<Decoration key={i++} {...child} />);
}
return (
    <div>{children} {this.state.something_else}</div>
);
```

The problem is that whenever I change some other state values, the render function of the **child** component gets called which is strange since I don't change anything in the `children` array. Any ideas? Is this code inefficient?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the temporary `children` variable, rather than just returning the result directly?

Comment: No, but honestly I don't know how to loop over the array directly from JSX.

Comment: use `map`. So just do `<div>{this.state.children.map((item, i) => <Decoration key={i} {...child} />)}</div>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default React re-render all components and sub components every time setState is called.

There is a method boolean shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState), each component has this method and its responsible to determine "should component update (run render function)?" every time you change state or pass new props from parent component.

You can write your own implementation of shouldComponentUpdate method for your component, but default implementation always returns true - meaning always re-run render function.

> By default, shouldComponentUpdate always returns true to prevent
>   subtle bugs when state is mutated in place, but if you are careful to
>   always treat state as immutable and to read only from props and state
>   in render() then you can override shouldComponentUpdate with an
>   implementation that compares the old props and state to their
>   replacements.
>    http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Thanks for the answer but doesn't React re-renders the components if there are changes in their state or props?

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Yes, which is why `shouldComponentUpdate` exists, so you can tell React whether or not the component *should* update.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move the code out of the `render()` method and put it into one of the lifecycle methods in this case it would be

`componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`. You can construct your `children` array there and simply disply it in the `render()` e.g.

```
render(){
  return (
      <div>{children} {this.state.something_else}</div>
  );
}
```